# Freezing an app icon's activity in the dock (or running it without ever going there)

Tags: memory, dock, icon

I have this program that displays the speed of uploads and downloads in the dock icon itself and is constantly updating in real time.

There is no way to disable this through the program preferences and hiding the dock doesn't stop it either.

After a few hours of running, the dock process memory use grows and grows, it can take gigs of memory and I believe this is because of this program as it doesn't happen otherwise.

I can killall Dock in terminal to reset but from googling I couldn't find anything related to this freezing a busy dock icon, only bouncing icons and dock animation,

Is there a way to freeze an icon or run an app without ever going to the dock?

Comment: What's the name of the app, and have you contacted the developer?

Comment: folx, torrent client, came as part of a subscription app thing I use, I'm sure I can use at least 10 better clients without this problem but I like the 'aggressiveness' of the download connections on this one, I suppose I'll just killall the dock when the memory gets too big, but it's a pretty big oversight on the devs part.

Comment: I emailed dev, looked before but didn't see an address but managed to find one, thanks for that advice.